# js create advance prototype

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

I am working in a project where most of the time I have to import the `computed style` of `html divs`... so I have tried to create a custom `prototype` under `Object` to make my code little nice, simple and shorter... here is the code that works for me...

```
Object.prototype.css=function(){
    return window.getComputedStyle(this);
}
```

when `var a` is the `node` of an `html div` and I need the `height` of that `div`, I have to use the `prototype` like below...

```
a.css().height;
```

Now the question is... how can I modify my `function` to use the `prototype` like...

```
a.css.height; // css insead of css()
```

**no jQuery please...**

Comment: Tried a.offsetHeight() in javascript?

Comment: @saji89 every time I will not need the height of a div... to get the `margin-top`, I want to use it like `a.css.marginTop;`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need it to act *like* an property, you have to give up some compatibility. For only modern browsers support [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

Here is an example:

```
function SomeType() {}
Object.defineProperty(SomeType.prototype, 'att', {
  get: function() {
    return this.att_;
  },
  set: function(value) {
    this.att_ = value;
  }
});
```

And in your case, you can extend `HTMLElement` or `HTMLDivElement`'s prototypes. Where `HTMLDivElement`'s prototype is inherited from `HTMLElement`'s. So you can do it like:

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, 'css', {
  get: function(){
    return window.getComputedStyle(this);
  }
});
```

Comment: wonderful... your code works for me... please share your source... means from where you learn this tricks... and what is the capability version for each browser... please share...

Comment: `Object.defineProperty()` is a link. follow the link.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, functions are first class objects. Basically, a function definition is just like any other variable. You can assign all of the following to a property:

```
a.css = "some value";
a.css = 22;
a.css = function() { return 1; };
```

now if you try to print them:

```
a.css //"some value"
a.css //22
a.css //function (){return 1;}
```

In order to invoke the function, you need to call `a.css()`. One way to get the desired behavior would be to execute the function and bind the output to another property.

```
Object.prototype.makeCSSProperty=function(){
    this.css = window.getComputedStyle(this);
}

a.makeCSSProperty();
a.css.height;
```

However, this property will be static and only reflect the style as it existed when you ran the `makeCSSProperty()` method.